Using SIMD To Parallelize Matrix Multiplication For A 4x4, Row-Major Matrix
I am currently facing an extremely hard time trying to parallelize a 4x4 matrix-multiplication algorithm. I am trying to make a library to use in a minimal raytracer project for school, so I'm trying to make its conventions as user-friendly as possible, which is why I chose to store matrices in a row-major order, as that seemed more intuitive for most people I asked. However, this poses an issue, as a lot of parallelization strategies require column extraction (for dot-product simplifications), and I'm facing a very hard time trying to even think in parallel... Here's my current matrix-multiplication code (with some missing parts) for computing the matrix product of two 4x4 matrices (row-major).
static inline __m128    _extract_column_ps4(const t_mat4s *in, int c)
{
    return (_mm_set_ps(in->a[3][c], in->a[2][c], in->a[1][c], in->a[0][c]));
}

static inline __m128    compute_row(const __m128 *in1, const t_mat4s *in2,
                            int r)
{
    __m128  col[4];
    __m128  mul[4];
    __m128  res;

    col[0] = _extract_column_ps4(in2, 0);
    col[1] = _extract_column_ps4(in2, 1);
    col[2] = _extract_column_ps4(in2, 2);
    col[3] = _extract_column_ps4(in2, 3);
    mul[0] = _mm_mul_ps(in1[r], col[0]);
    mul[1] = _mm_mul_ps(in1[r], col[1]);
    mul[2] = _mm_mul_ps(in1[r], col[2]);
    mul[3] = _mm_mul_ps(in1[r], col[3]);
    // ..
    // ..
    return (res);
}

/// @brief computes the cross product of `in1` with `in2`
///        (in that order), and stores the result in the `t_mat4s`
///        pointed-to by `out`.
static inline void  lag_mat4s_cross_mat4s(const t_mat4s in1,
                            const t_mat4s in2, t_mat4s *out)
{
    out->simd[0] = compute_row(in1.simd, &in2, 0);
    out->simd[1] = compute_row(in1.simd, &in2, 1);
    out->simd[2] = compute_row(in1.simd, &in2, 2);
    out->simd[3] = compute_row(in1.simd, &in2, 3);
}

As you can see, I'm not using any hadds, in fact, I'm trying to avoid them, as they are very expensive. Another approach can be to simply do something like:
// Code for computing the result of multiplying two 4x4 row-major matrix of double-precision floats

static inline void  unrolled_cross(const t_mat4d *in, const __m256d col[4],
                        t_mat4d *out)
{
    out->r1.x = lag_dot_product_avx(in->r1.simd, col[0]);
    out->r1.y = lag_dot_product_avx(in->r1.simd, col[1]);
    out->r1.z = lag_dot_product_avx(in->r1.simd, col[2]);
    out->r1.w = lag_dot_product_avx(in->r1.simd, col[3]);
    out->r2.x = lag_dot_product_avx(in->r2.simd, col[0]);
    out->r2.y = lag_dot_product_avx(in->r2.simd, col[1]);
    out->r2.z = lag_dot_product_avx(in->r2.simd, col[2]);
    out->r2.w = lag_dot_product_avx(in->r2.simd, col[3]);
    out->r3.x = lag_dot_product_avx(in->r3.simd, col[0]);
    out->r3.y = lag_dot_product_avx(in->r3.simd, col[1]);
    out->r3.z = lag_dot_product_avx(in->r3.simd, col[2]);
    out->r3.w = lag_dot_product_avx(in->r3.simd, col[3]);
    out->r4.x = lag_dot_product_avx(in->r4.simd, col[0]);
    out->r4.y = lag_dot_product_avx(in->r4.simd, col[1]);
    out->r4.z = lag_dot_product_avx(in->r4.simd, col[2]);
    out->r4.w = lag_dot_product_avx(in->r4.simd, col[3]);
}

void    lag_mat4_cross(const t_mat4d *in, const t_mat4d *in2, t_mat4d *out)
{
    __m256d col[4];

    lag_extract_column4_avx(in2, 0, &col[0]);
    lag_extract_column4_avx(in2, 1, &col[1]);
    lag_extract_column4_avx(in2, 2, &col[2]);
    lag_extract_column4_avx(in2, 3, &col[3]);
    unrolled_cross(in, col, out);
}

Which works perfectly fine to be fair, but I feel like I'm losing on a lot of parallelization here...
I first tried shuffling, but quickly realised it's not gonna work, as my columns aren't contiguous in memory. I also tried using a sequence of _mm_mul_ps's followed by two _mm_add_ps's, which obviously didn't work, because you'd need to add the elements horizontally rather than in parallel (component-wise). I was thinking of using an AVX-256 register to store two sets of 4 packed-singles, but that also gets rather heavy, and my brain got fried trying to even conceptualise it. Any ideas/suggestions? I don't think converting to column-major is an option for me, at this time... Also, could you give me advice on performance the order I store my matrices in (column-major vs row-major). What would be the performance implications? Is any way better than the other? Is it case-by-case? Why?
Edit: I should probably mention that my structures/unions look like this:
typedef union u_vec4s
{
    float       a[4];
    __m128      simd;
    struct
    {
        float   x;
        float   y;
        float   z;
        float   w;
    };
}__attribute((aligned(16))) t_vec4s;

typedef union u_mat4s
{
    float   a[4][4];
    __m128  simd[4];
    struct
    {
        t_vec4s r1;
        t_vec4s r2;
        t_vec4s r3;
        t_vec4s r4;
    };
}__attribute((aligned(16))) t_mat4s;


Edit #2:
Here's my revised code:
static inline __m128    _extract_column_ps4(const t_mat4s *in, int c)
{
    return (_mm_set_ps(in->a[3][c], in->a[2][c], in->a[1][c], in->a[0][c]));
}

/// @brief Returns the cross product of a `t_mat4s` with a `t_vec4s`
///        (in that order).
static inline t_vec4s   lag_mat4s_cross_vec4s(const t_mat4s m,
                            const t_vec4s v)
{
    t_vec4s ret;

    ret.x = lag_vec4s_dot_ret(m.r1, v);
    ret.y = lag_vec4s_dot_ret(m.r2, v);
    ret.z = lag_vec4s_dot_ret(m.r3, v);
    ret.w = lag_vec4s_dot_ret(m.r4, v);
    return (ret);
}

static inline __m128    compute_row(const __m128 *in1, const t_mat4s *in2,
                            int r)
{
    t_mat4s cols;
    t_vec4s row;
    __m128  mul[4];
    __m128  add[2];

    cols.simd[0] = _extract_column_ps4(in2, 0);
    cols.simd[1] = _extract_column_ps4(in2, 1);
    cols.simd[2] = _extract_column_ps4(in2, 2);
    cols.simd[3] = _extract_column_ps4(in2, 3);
    row.simd = in1[r];
    return (lag_mat4s_cross_vec4s(cols, row).simd);
}

/// @brief computes the cross product of `in1` with `in2`
///        (in that order), and stores the result in the `t_mat4s`
///        pointed-to by `out`.
static inline void  lag_mat4s_cross_mat4s(const t_mat4s in1,
                            const t_mat4s in2, t_mat4s *out)
{
    out->simd[0] = compute_row(in1.simd, &in2, 0);
    out->simd[1] = compute_row(in1.simd, &in2, 1);
    out->simd[2] = compute_row(in1.simd, &in2, 2);
    out->simd[3] = compute_row(in1.simd, &in2, 3);
}

I'm going for a different strategy, now, wherein I calculate the matrix-vector product, assuming each row is its own vector, multiplied by the same matrix flipped (its columns become its rows). This works, is there a better way to do this..?

You tagged this [glm-math].  Are you actually using that library?  The tag says it's C++ but you're writing in [c].  And you're talking about SSE/AVX intrinsics, not OpenGL shaders.

There are several existing Q&As, like (Vec4 x Mat4x4) product using SIMD and improvements and Efficient 4x4 matrix vector multiplication with SSE: horizontal add and dot product - what's the point? and especially Efficient 4x4 matrix multiplication (C vs assembly).  AVX has very efficient broadcast-loads (vbroadcastss)

You can also use FMA if you have that as well as AVX1, further reducing the amount of work for a 4x4 matmul, making the CPU more able to overlap multiple such operations or overlap with surrounding code.

Hello, @PeterCordes! Thanks a lot for taking the time to reply. I will check out the links you have provided, the reason why I tagged this as glm-math is because I hoped to attract people who possibly understand the implementations there, as they are SIMD-heavy, and very good as a reference for my purposes! The thing that scares me out of using FMA is that the latency and throughput of those instructions seem to be worse than using a combination of muls and adds (theoretically). I was looking into using the AVX registers, too, so I'll give that a shot (I do have them on my device)

GPU SIMD works very differently from CPU SIMD for stuff like this.  CPU SIMD uses contiguous short vectors, while GPU SIMD lets different "threads" work on different elements.  Also, the throughput cost of an FMA is the same as one FP ADD or FP MUL, so you get nearly twice the throughput from using FMA for a problem like matmul.  The latency is 1 cycle longer than vaddps on Alder Lake and later, but the dep chains are very short for a 4x4 matmul, only one mul and 3 FMAs, and there's a lot of parallel work for out-of-order exec to overlap.

@PeterCordes. I see, I looked through the links you have provided, and they do seem to favour column-major matrices. Since I'm using _mm_dp_ps in my dot-product function, I feel like I'm slowing it by a lot, do you think I should continue with the same approach but modify my dot-product function to use horizontal-adds instead, or should I transpose the matrix and work with it as column-major, or perhaps even just make the function its own inlined implementation? Could you show me an example as to how you'd do the mul, 3xFMA thing? I'm curious to see it in action

In Efficient 4x4 matrix multiplication (C vs assembly) , for each output row it's doing 4x mul and 3x add summing the products.  That can be contracted into 1x mul and 3x FMA (in a different order, not a tree of additions, instead relying on out-of-order exec to hide the latency.)  That function works with row-major for AxB, loading the 4 whole rows of B, and broadcasting the elements of a single row of A to produce a whole row of C in one SIMD vector with no horizontal ops needed.  (With 128-bit vectors; 256 is trickier.)

@PeterCordes. Thank you so much for all the suggestions and resources. You have been truly of great help. I suppose I have one last question for you: what are some online communities where you and others interested in the topic of optimisation and graphics programming (perhaps more on the optimisation side of things) hang out? I'm very new to this field, I've only dabbled around in it for around a couple weeks or so. I'd love to expand my horizons and find mentors along the way, or just friends who are interested in this stuff

I pretty much only hang out on Stack Overflow, where stuff I write is mostly findable for future readers searching on the same thing. That's what makes it feel worth the effort to explain things in detail, and not have to write the same answer multiple times.

If you are not restricted to use plain C or are not allowed to use existing libraries, I strongly recommend using the Eigen library for matrix operations: https://godbolt.org/z/sP1jdqejq

I'm not allowed to use external libraries for the calculations. That would get me a big fat fail. I'm technically going above-and-beyond, as they didn't really ask for optimisation or even real-time rendering. I just wanna add SIMD to my suite of optimisation techniques, and well, I kinda got addicted as it is, according to my limited understanding, the highest form of compiler suggestions haha. @chtz

Alright. I came to the conclusion that using AVX registers for this is the best approach for a 4x4 row-major matrix (no benchmarks to support my claim), simply due to the fact that broadcast-loads are more efficient apparently. Also decided to avoid spamming _mm_dp_ps in my lag_mat4s_cross_vec4s function. Here's the revised code:
static inline __m128    _extract_column_ps4(const t_mat4s *in, int c)
{
    return (_mm_set_ps(in->a[3][c], in->a[2][c], in->a[1][c], in->a[0][c]));
}

/// @brief Returns the cross product of a `t_mat4s` with a `t_vec4s`
///        (in that order).
static inline t_vec4s   lag_mat4s_cross_vec4s(const t_mat4s m,
                            const t_vec4s v)
{
    t_vec4s         ret;
    const __m128    mul0 = _mm_mul_ps(m.simd[0], v.simd);
    const __m128    mul1 = _mm_mul_ps(m.simd[1], v.simd);
    const __m128    mul2 = _mm_mul_ps(m.simd[2], v.simd);
    const __m128    mul3 = _mm_mul_ps(m.simd[3], v.simd);


    ret.simd = _mm_hadd_ps(_mm_hadd_ps(mul0, mul1), _mm_hadd_ps(mul2, mul3));
    return (ret);
}

//static inline void    lag_mat4s_cross_mat4s(const t_mat4s in1,
//                          const t_mat4s in2, t_mat4s *out)
//{
//  t_mat4s cols;

//  cols.simd[0] = _extract_column_ps4(&in2, 0);
//  cols.simd[1] = _extract_column_ps4(&in2, 1);
//  cols.simd[2] = _extract_column_ps4(&in2, 2);
//  cols.simd[3] = _extract_column_ps4(&in2, 3);
//  out->r1 = lag_mat4s_cross_vec4s(cols, in1.r1);
//  out->r2 = lag_mat4s_cross_vec4s(cols, in1.r2);
//  out->r3 = lag_mat4s_cross_vec4s(cols, in1.r3);
//  out->r4 = lag_mat4s_cross_vec4s(cols, in1.r4);
//}

/// @brief computes the cross product of `in1` with `in2`
///        (in that order), and stores the result in the `t_mat4s`
///        pointed-to by `out`.
static inline void  lag_mat4s_cross_mat4s(const t_mat4s in1,
                        const t_mat4s in2, t_mat4s *out)
{
    __m256  a[2];
    __m256  b[2];
    __m256  c[8];
    __m256  t[2];
    __m256  u[2];

    t[0] = in1._ymm[0];
    t[1] = in1._ymm[1];
    u[0] = in2._ymm[0];
    u[1] = in2._ymm[1];
    a[0] = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t[0], t[0], _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 0, 0, 0));
    a[1] = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t[1], t[1], _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 0, 0, 0));
    b[0] = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(u[0], u[0], 0x00);
    c[0] = _mm256_mul_ps(a[0], b[0]);
    c[1] = _mm256_mul_ps(a[1], b[0]);
    a[0] = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t[0], t[0], _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 1, 1, 1));
    a[1] = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t[1], t[1], _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 1, 1, 1));
    b[0] = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(u[0], u[0], 0x11);
    c[2] = _mm256_mul_ps(a[0], b[0]);
    c[3] = _mm256_mul_ps(a[1], b[0]);
    a[0] = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t[0], t[0], _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 2, 2, 2));
    a[1] = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t[1], t[1], _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 2, 2, 2));
    b[1] = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(u[1], u[1], 0x00);
    c[4] = _mm256_mul_ps(a[0], b[1]);
    c[5] = _mm256_mul_ps(a[1], b[1]);
    a[0] = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t[0], t[0], _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 3, 3));
    a[1] = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t[1], t[1], _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 3, 3));
    b[1] = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(u[1], u[1], 0x11);
    c[6] = _mm256_mul_ps(a[0], b[1]);
    c[7] = _mm256_mul_ps(a[1], b[1]);
    c[0] = _mm256_add_ps(c[0], c[2]);
    c[4] = _mm256_add_ps(c[4], c[6]);
    c[1] = _mm256_add_ps(c[1], c[3]);
    c[5] = _mm256_add_ps(c[5], c[7]);
    out->_ymm[0] = _mm256_add_ps(c[0], c[4]);
    out->_ymm[1] = _mm256_add_ps(c[1], c[5]);
}

I stole an implementation from a post that Peter so kindly provided (I didn't just copy-paste. I understand what's going on). I am wondering, however, if performance would be boosted if I align my structs to a 32-byte region instead of 16. Not my concern as of now, but feel free to comment your thoughts; any piece of information and criticism is welcome!

That's a lot of shuffling compared to the amount of FMAs (and no broadcast loads, although those aren't directly usable when you need to broadcast different elements in the high vs. low lanes).  Should run well on Zen 2 and later, and probably Ice Lake and later if those shuffles can run on the port 1 shuffle unit (https://uops.info/).  https://godbolt.org/z/GPj1Ezvvz shows it compiles decently with -ffp-contract=fast to let it actually use FMAs.  (And I used -ffast-math for clang to let it do one more contraction which your source order of operations seems to have defeated)

Hmm... I'm presuming this means that this version is subpar, huh? Haha @PeterCordes. I can give it one more run if you recommend! I'm making this library for a minimal real-time raytracer, so I'm loving the feedback you've been providing. Also, will definitely use godbolt in the future, I didn't know such a tool existed!!

Well assuming you're targeting a machine with FMA, since the only CPUs with AVX1 but not FMA are very obsolete by now (Sandy/Ivy Bridge, and Bulldozer-family), yeah that's a major missed optimization for front-end throughput and back-end ports.  I'd aim to write code that compiles the way -ffast-math does even if you don't use fast-math.  (And manually use FMA intrinsics since clang's default is -ffp-contract=on (within expressions, not across statements), not fast.

The amount of shuffling might be worth it if that's unavoidable for 256-bit vectors, if that's fewer total uops, and if the shuffle bottleneck is no worse than the FMA bottleneck you'd get from using 128-bit vectors and simple broadcast loads.  Might even be worth mixing matmuls that use 128 and 256-bit vectors to fully utilize the relevant execution ports on Zen 2-4, if this leaves some underused.  On Intel P-cores, as long as enough of those shuffles can run on port 1, all of ports 0, 1, and 5 should be busy with some mix of FMAs and shuffles.  Ice Lake and later can run vshufps on p1/5

@PeterCordes a whole-lot of terminology I don't understand... "uops", "broadcast loads", "Zen 2-4", "P-cores", "ports", "p1/5"... I'm so sorry, could you guide me through what you mean, or at the very least, tell me where to start my research..? haha..

https://agner.org/optimize/ especially his microarch guide for micro-ops (aka uops), execution-ports, and CPU internals.  Zen 2, Zen 3, and Zen 4 are x86 microarchitectures from AMD.  e.g. https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2 .  P-cores are the performance cores (as opposed to Efficiency-cores) in recent Intel hybrid CPUs.  (What are performance and efficiency cores in Intel's 12th Generation Alder lake CPU Line?).

front-end is the fetch/decode part of a CPU, the back-end is where out-of-order exec happens.  https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/ / https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/10/

@PeterCordes very well. Thanks a lot!
